# What is the best practice to deploy SPD workflow into production?

Tags: workflow

What is the best practice to deploy SPD workflow into production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got a little better in SharePoint 2010. You can save a reusable workflow as a .wsp (SharePoint solution file) and publish it on the server that way. Works best if you have Visual Studio.  I haven't tried it without it, but I might just to see how it works.

There is a walk-thru on the MSDN site at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231580.aspx

There are some other suggestions at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/3ccc0692-4fe7-4ef1-a311-fae29e7afdad